# What happens if I run out of checkmarx scan for a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, appexchange, 2gp, 1gp-package

Below is a picture of a checkmarx scan for a managed package version. What happens if I run out of scans, and how can I get more scans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will note that you get scans per version. You can, therefore, create a new version (e.g. a beta release) to get more scans.

We have previously requested Salesforce to provide a full Checkmarx scan (rather than the first 500 issues per type truncated scan the online tool produces) after running out of scans. We did this through an AppExchange security review partner support case.

NB: we did have to provide the full set of metadata to the Salesforce Security team member who did this for us, which is an uncomfortable experience...